# Create object with combination of parameters

Tags: c++, opengl

I try to design class for shader program. 
Shader program may consist of several shaders object with different type.
I don't want create diffrent consturctors for every combination or create setters and after this calling member function to create program. I try to find good looking solution or use design pattern, but i don't know good one.
I have 5 different type of shaders and always I'm must pass to shader program at least two(always vertex and fragment shaders). I need shaders only for create shader program, after this I don't need them any more.

Option #1:

```
ShaderPogram(VertexShader vs, FragmentShader fs);
ShaderPogram(VertexShader vs, GeometryShader geometry, FragmentShader fs);
```

Option #2:

```
struct Collection {
 VertexShader vs; GeometryShader gs; FragmentShader fs;
};

ShaderProgram(Collection c);
```

Option #3:

```
class ShaderProgram {
public:
 void SetVertexShader(VertexShader vs);
 void SetGeometryShader(GeometryShader gs);
 void SetFragmentShader(FramgentShader fs);
};
```

Maybe someone can propose other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your options #2 and #3 seem just fine.  Except in option #3, since you say the vertex and fragment shaders are always required, I'd give the class a constructor that takes those two types and setters for only the optional types.

But if you really want to go fancy to make things even easier for users of the class, some template work can make it so that you can use just one constructor, and pass any valid set of shader arguments in any order you like:

```
#include <type_traits>

namespace ShaderProgramDetail {
    template <typename Type, typename... TypeList> struct type_in_list;
    template <typename Type>
    struct type_in_list<Type>
        : public std::false_type {};
    template <typename Type, typename... Rest>
    struct type_in_list<Type, Type, Rest...>
        : public std::true_type {};
    template <typename Type, typename First, typename... Rest>
    struct type_in_list<Type, First, Rest...>
        : public std::integral_constant<bool,
            type_in_list<Type, Rest...>::value> {};

    template <typename... Types> struct types_unique;
    template <>
    struct types_unique<> : public std::true_type {};
    template <typename Type1, typename... Rest>
    struct types_unique<Type1, Rest...>
        : public std::integral_constant<bool,
            !type_in_list<Type1, Rest...>::value &&
            types_unique<Rest...>::value> {};

    template <bool... B> struct all_of;
    template <>
    struct all_of<> : public std::true_type {};
    template <bool... B>
    struct all_of<false, B...> : public std::false_type {};
    template <bool... B>
    struct all_of<true, B...>
        : public std::integral_constant<bool, all_of<B...>::value> {};
}

class ShaderProgram
{
public:
    template <typename... Shaders>
    explicit ShaderProgram(Shaders&& ... shaders) {
        using namespace ShaderProgramDetail;
        static_assert(types_unique<std::decay_t<Shaders>...>::value,
            "Cannot provide two shaders of the same type");
        static_assert(all_of<type_in_list<std::decay_t<Shaders>,
            VertexShader, FragmentShader, GeometryShader>
            ::value...>::value,
            "Invalid argument type");
        static_assert(type_in_list<VertexShader, std::decay_t<Shaders>...>::value,
            "Missing VertexShader argument");
        static_assert(type_in_list<FragmentShader, std::decay_t<Shaders>...>::value,
            "Missing FragmentShader argument");
        using int_arr = int[];
        (void) int_arr{ ( init_shader(std::forward<Shaders>(shaders)), 0 )... };
    }
private:
    void init_shader(VertexShader vs) { vertex_shader = std::move(vs); }
    void init_shader(FragmentShader fs) { fragment_shader = std::move(fs); }
    void init_shader(GeometryShader gs) { geometry_shader = std::move(gs); }

    VertexShader vertex_shader;
    FragmentShader fragment_shader;
    GeometryShader geometry_shader;
};
```

Note I've used four `static_assert` statements in the constructor to validate:

- No type of shader is passed more than once.
- Every argument is a supported shader type. (You'll probably want to expand the list of valid types used there.)
- The required type `VertexShader` is present.
- The required type `FragmentShader` is present.

The class templates in `namespace ShaderProgramDetail` are rather general.  If you think you might reuse them somewhere else, you could put them in their own header file and rename the namespace to something more appropriate.

The above is valid C++14 code.

If you're stuck with C++11, you'll need to either replace every `std::decay_t<X>` with `typename std::decay<X>::type`, or define a `decay_t` of your own:

```
template <typename T>
using decay_t = typename std::decay_t<T>::type;
```

If you're using C++17, you could use `std::conjunction` instead of `ShaderProgramDetail::all_of`; and the last two lines of the constructor could be more simply written:

```
init_shader(std::forward<Shaders>(shaders)), ... ;
```